# Converting a string to a mySql DECIMAL type

Tags: php, mysql, html, string, decimal

I am trying to insert data about an item's price from an HTML form into a mySQL database. The input field is defined as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="price" value="0.00"/>
```

The form is POSTed to the next page in which the database stuff is taken care of. Currently I just enter the exact contents of $_POST['price'] into the database field, which has type DECIMAL(4,2). I heard that this was stored as a string but the database throws an error whenever I try and do this. Is there a PHP function for converting between strings and the MySQL DECIMAL type? Or will I have to do some formatting myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never just "*enter the exact contents of `$_POST['...']`*" into any database field : it's a door opened to SQL Injections.

Instead, you must make sure the data you are injection into your SQL queries are actually valid, according to the expected DB datatypes.

For decimals, a solution, on the PHP side, would be to use the `floatval` function :

```
$clean_price = floatval($_POST['price']);
$query = "insert into your_table (price, ...) values ($clean_price, ...)"
if (mysql_query($query)) {
    // success
} else {
    echo mysql_error();   // To help, while testing
}
```

Note that I didn't put any quote arround the value ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't floatval() cause some loss of precision if we were to perform any arithmetic on `$clean_price`? Not sure if PHP has a built-in decimal type...but in this case, wouldn't it be better to sanitize the POST data and pass it in as a string?